# tri-state RAM switch

Tags: ram

[image]

The picture shows the truth table of control operation of a RAM. If you disable the OE pin the output can not come to the bus because of high impedance, now the question is, is the impedance unidirectional like a diode? if not how can write data function still be possible when OE is high? because in this situation the data input should not reach the ram. in other word is the tri-state switch bi-directional or unidirectional?

Comment: Think of a buffer or OPAMP input. It is high impedance, that is no current is flowing into or out of it. Yet it serves as an input.

Comment: @Eugene Sh  suppose I have enabled the WE pin, and also CE pins. at this particular moment the pins will "become" input port and if I disable WE the same ports will converted into output port, is that correct? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OE simply disables the output drivers so it can't drive the data bus, i.e. does not push high or pull low.

Therefore from the perspective of this memory chip, the bus is free so that some other device like the host CPU or another identical memory chip can drive the data bus for reading or writing.

Even if OE is high, the WE can be used to write data to this memory chip, the data is not written to memory without the WE being active.

Comment: upvote for your clarification, one thing I would like to ask , In an actual RAM data input and output pins are separate or same pins can be used for both Input and output?

Comment: The HM628512BI is an actual RAM chip, and it uses same pins for both input and output, like every other standard memory chip does, so it does not use separate input and output pins.

Comment: suppose I have enabled the WE pin, and also CE pins. at this particular moment the pins will "become" input port and if I disable WE the same ports will converted into output port, is that correct?

Comment: No. OE and CE have to be active for the chip to output  data. The data sheet will have timing diagrams that detail the time required for things to change.